# Codeigniter 2.1 - MySQL CONCAT (append string)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have PHP code like this:

```
$query = 'UPDATE  `user_vote` SET `container` = CONCAT(`container`, ' ;
$query .=  ",$glas";
$query .= ') WHERE `user_id` = ' . $id_u;
$this->db->query($query);
```

When I run this code, I got following error:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column ',iljadu' in 'field list'
>
> UPDATE `user_vote` SET `container` = CONCAT(`container`, `,iljadu`)
>   WHERE `user_id` = 4

What is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing quotes around your variable for the `concat()`

```
$query = 'UPDATE  `user_vote` SET `container` = CONCAT(`container`, ' ;
$query .=  ",'$glas'";
$query .= ') WHERE `user_id` = ' . $id_u;
$this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: `$glas` could contain a column identifier, but I suspect you are correct. Still too many commas though... ;-)

Comment: @DaveRandom `Concat()` can contain a column name or a string. In this case my big nose is telling me that it is a string that is being appended with a column - in which case there are quotes missing around it. I got a good feeling about this one :)

Comment: This is working, thank you :). @DaveRandom I need coma, but I put it at wrong place. **",'$glas'";** should be **"',$glas'";** and everything works fine.

Comment: @Sasha Super, feel free to Accept the answer and we can all call it a night :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query .=  ",$glas";
```

should be

```
$query .=  "$glas";
```

Comment: `Concat()` has parameters that are separated by commas?