# Update data without deleting old files with code at CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have data like the example below, when I try to add new data, the example I want to add the name `philips` on the `id` `02` but after I update the name `ana, jack` to remove and the name `philips` is stored, is there any other way to update the table with as add one name without deleting the old data?

```
 id   |         name       |  class
--------------------------------------
 01   | smith, john, billy |   III
 02   | ana, jack,         |   IV
```

Controllers

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);;
$this->my_model->update_name($id);
```

Models

```
function update_name($id) {
    $data = array(                  
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'));              
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('mytable', $data);
}
```

Comment: Concat the existing value with the new value.
EG:
UPDATE mytable SET column= CONCAT(column, ',', 'NEW_value') WHERE CONDTN;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL `CONCAT()`, in your case it will be like this:

```
function update_name($id) {
    $name = $this->input->post('name');                  

    $this->db->set('name', "CONCAT(name,', ','".$name."')", FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('mytable', $data);
}
```

P.S: Its better not to access your post input in your model, instead you should validate it in your controller and then pass it to your model as a parameter.

Comment: thank you very much your answer is more simple and my problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two options here, the first is to collect the information from the field and use PHP to join the two strings together.

```
$current_names = $this->db->select( 'name' )->from( 'mytable' )-.where( 'id', $id )->get()->result();
$new_names = $current_names.', '.$this->input->post( 'name' );

function update_name($id) {
    $data = array(                  
                  'name' => $new_names
                 );              
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('mytable', $data);
}
```

The second is to use a more traditional sql statement with a concat, I have not tested this but something close to this should work.

```
$query = 'UPDATE  `mytable` SET name = CONCAT(`name`, ' ;
$query .=  ",'$this->input->post( 'name' )'";
$query .= ') WHERE `id` = ' . $id;
$this->db->query($query);
```

This approach was taken from here and although it is CI2 it should still work, [Codeigniter 2.1 - MySQL CONCAT (append string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902345/codeigniter-2-1-mysql-concat-append-string)

Comment: thank you for your answers, but the answers Neal easier I understand, and your answer is also very helpful to solve my problems with other methods and it adds to my knowledge.