# Unable to delete with checkboxes and update codeignitrer

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Previously I've had a problem How can update the data without deleting existing files [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150785/update-data-without-deleting-old-files-with-code-at-codeigniter), and it has been resolved. but I have problems again after I have updated the data and I want to delete one of these data for example, delete the name `jack` and update it but it does not work? what is missing

```
 id   |         name       |  class
--------------------------------------
 01   | smith, john, billy |   III
 02   | ana, jack, philips |   IV
```

Controllers

```
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);;
$this->my_model->update_name($id);
```

Models

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');                     
$delete = $this->input->post('delete');

for ($i=0; $i < count($delete) ; $i++)  { 
        $this->db->where('name', $delete[$i]);
        $this->db->delete('mytable');
}

$this->db->set('name', "CONCAT(name,'".$name."')", FALSE);                  
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('mytable');
```

Views

```
<span class="button-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="danger">'.$row.'</button>
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="delete[]" value="'.row.'"/>
</span>
```

Comment: You really are making life more difficult for yourself then it needs to be.  Change the structure of the database so that each row contains a single id, name and class.  This will allow for the updating, deleting and creation to be perform so much easier.

Comment: yes, I think there is something wrong with my script and I had to try again to understand the database structure, is actually the main problem I can not display the current value edit data with jquery.tokeninput.js so I looked for other ways to edit and update the data.

Answer (score 0):

You fail to delete or update with input `jack` value is because you use `where()` which will translate into SQL statement

```
... WHERE name = 'jack'
```

But the field `name` only contains part of the value `ana, jack, philips` so comparison will result to false. As pointed out by Blinkdamo you need to normalize your database schema first.

Comment: well thanks i try to improve and learn normalize  database schema to address these issues